# How can I stop certain part of my php script from executing? (to make my page load faster)

Tags: php, pagination

```
<?php
$rows_per_page = 2;
$cols_per_page = 2;
$image_href = '<a href=/';
$image_links = array('file1/page1>', 'file2/page2>', 'file3/page3>',  
'file4/page4>',   'file5/page5>', 'file6/page6>', 'file6/page6>',  
'file/page7>', 'file/page8>', 'subfile/page9>');
$img_srcs = '<img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/imagetitle/';
$images = array();

for($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    $images[$i] = $i;
}
$image_ending = '.png" height="200" width="200" /></a>';
$image_descriptions = array('<br />something', '<br />description', 
'<br />arbitrary', 'random', '<br />you', '<br />get', '<br />the',  
'<br />idea', '<br />itsdescriptions');  
$total_images = count($images);
$images_per_page = $rows_per_page * $cols_per_page;
$total_images = count($images);
$total_pages = ceil($total_images / $images_per_page);
$current_page = (int) $_GET['page'];
if($current_page<1 || $current_page>$total_pages)
{
    $current_page = 1;
}

//Get records for the current page
$page_image_links = array_splice($image_links, ($current_page-1)*$images_per_page, $images_per_page);
$page_images = array_splice($images, ($current_page-1)*$images_per_page, $images_per_page);
$page_image_descriptions = array_splice($image_descriptions, ($current_page-1)*$images_per_page, $images_per_page);
$slots = "<table border=\"1\">";
for($row=0; $row<$rows_per_page; $row++)
{
    $slots .= "<tr>";
    for($col=0; $col<$cols_per_page; $col++)
    {
        $imgIdx = ($row * $rows_per_page) + $col;
        $img = (isset($page_images[$imgIdx])) ? "{$image_href}{$page_image_links[$imgIdx]}{$img_srcs}{$page_images[$imgIdx]}{$image_ending}{$page_image_descriptions[$imgIdx]}" : '&nbsp;';
        $slots .= "<td>$img</td>";
    }
    $slots .= "</tr>";
}
$slots .= "</table>";

//Create pagination links
$first = "First";
$prev  = "Prev";
$next  = "Next";
$last  = "Last";
if($current_page>1)
{
    $prevPage = $current_page - 1;
    $first = "<a href=\"blah.php?page=1\">First</a>";
    $prev  = "<a href=\"blah.php?page={$prevPage}\">Prev</a>";
}
if($current_page<$total_pages)
{
    $nextPage = $current_page + 1;
    $next = "<a href=\"blah.php?page={$nextPage}\">Next</a>";
    $last = "<a href=\"blah.php?page={$total_pages}\">Last</a>";
}

?>
<html>
<title></title>
<body>
<h2>Here are the records for page <?php echo $current_page; ?></h2>
  <ul>
    <?php echo $slots; ?>
  </ul>
Page <?php echo $current_page; ?> of <?php echo $total_pages; ?>
<br />
<?php echo "{$first} | {$prev} | {$next} | {$last}"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

So basically this code above makes it easy to put up images and their links. For now, I don't have that many images, so the page runs super fast. However, I'm thinking in the long run. If I have say, 10,000 images, it's gonna take a long time to process each paginated page, as I would have $image_links of file1/page1 up to file10000/page10000, and 10000 descriptions! Is there a way to stop the web browser from reading, or skip, certain parts of the script (the $image_links and $image_descriptions in my case)? That way, it won't need to read through all 10000 $image_links and $image_descriptions.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there's any way to get around loading up the array with all of the image links, desc, etc. Your page isn't actually looping through every array element; you're figuring out the index range of the items that you need, then getting those items out of the array. On the up side, you aren't looping though them. On the down side, you need every item in there, in order for the index calculation to work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to suggest another approach. Using arrays for this is not ideal; it really feels like it should be a database driven app.

If you decide to go for that approach, pagination becomes much easier. You can just ask your database engine for the corresponding records. For example, in MySQL, you'd ask for the data something like this:

select * from tableA order by id limit 10 offset 20;

This would return id's 21 thru 30.

... and, would scale much better. Of course, if you've never done any work with databases, there is quite a learning curve.

Comment: No, I've never done database, unfortunately. I think what I'm doing here definitely doesn't require a database though. It seems like a really easy stuff that I can't figure out. Besides, calling up a SQL database is slower than running pure php. Especially if I can exit some parts.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to end execution at a certain place, just call   exit;

Answer (score 0):

Try using the onload function on your < body >'s html, so it will load the page at once

Comment: I don't think I used the correct wording. I think I should have said skip. Cause I think my php script loads a bunch of unnecessary stuff.